# Cancelled ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS and now server won't boot

Tags: boot, server, uefi

SOLVED.

I cancelled the install as the title sais. The problem is now I can't boot into ubuntu, all it shows is a flashing underscore on a black background. I've tried resuming the download from the same USB, but it won't work. I've tried booting from ubuntu desktop live from another USB, but it  tries booting using the hard. Also tried entering BIOS, but I've found out that you can't enter BIOS if you install UEFI.
My question is how can I format the hard disk so that I start from scratch? Or if there is any other method of either resuming the install or start from scratch.
The server is a DELL PowerEdge T20.

Comment: It seems like I've been really stupid. On the keyboard I use for the server there is an F-lock button that prevented me from using F2 and so I couldn't get into BIOS, now everythimg is good.

Answer (score 0):

During reboot, press Del to get into system settings, then F8 to select which device to boot from. There, select your installation medium. Select UEFI version if you see both.
And yes, you have to install from beginning.